# Proper use of The Club?

Tags: ignition, locks, steering-wheel

I recently purchased The Club for my car (as it is a target for thieves) and I'm unclear on how to put it in. It says to turn the steering wheel one full rotation before putting it on, however, my cars steering wheel locks automatically when the keys aren't in the ignition. So I'm wondering if its necessary to turn the steering wheel before putting on The Club?

Comment: Yes. First turn the wheel, then remove the key from the ignition.

Comment: Don't see these abount much these days, the newer the car generally the harder it is to get into, so I think for that reasons car crime is on the down, as other crimes are easier with greater gain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of turning the wheel one turn is to put the wheels at a cant (other than straight). This is especially important on standard shift vehicles so it cannot just be put into neutral and moved. It just gives one more weapon in the arsenal against car thieves. The action of applying the club should be, before you turn the ignition off, turn the steering wheel one turn. Then put the club on the steering wheel so it is visible to all. As CodeBlend said, the club is a visual deterrent, but it is one more thing a thief must go through before they can actually steal a car. While the steering wheel lock and the club have the same basic purpose (to keep the wheel from turning), it does help with security. If you are in a high theft area, a thief will usually go for the easier target. With the club on your vehicle, you've just made your car a little harder to steal. If, however, you have a vehicle which is target of thieves, it won't really matter how you secure your vehicle: if it is wanted, they will find a way to take it. The best way to protect these types of vehicles is to keep them in a garage. The axiom "*Out of sight, out of mind*" holds true.

No security option is fool proof. Some are better than others, but if a thief wants your vehicle, they will find a way. This is one purpose of insurance (but that's another thread, in and of itself!). The key to the validity of the Club (as well as any other anti-theft measure) is to ensure you are using it *each and every time* you leave your vehicle. If you don't employ it, it will never work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your car already has a built-in steering wheel lock so The Club would have no benefit other than a visual deterrent and in that case it wouldn't matter how you put it on

Answer (score 1):

The idea of turning the wheel is to have the wheels turned to prevent movement of the car. After you park, turn the wheel prior to shutting off the car. I would suggest turning them towards the curb. If the ignition is removed by the thief the wheel will be unlocked. If the wheels were straight he would be able to drive the car albeit only in a straight line. With the wheels turned, the Club prevent the wheels being straightened and the thief can only drive into the curb.